# Windows Forms in powershell, display picturebox on bottom of page

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am making a windows form using powershell code.

I make the form, fill it with a couple of pictureboxes using a loop and then at the end I want to display a logo on the bottom of the page below all pictureboxes.

Form is created with these properties:

```
$form = new-object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Title"
$form.AutoSize=$true
$form.AutoSizeMode= "GrowAndShrink"
```

I add the pictureboxes which I need and then I use this code to create the logo.

```
$Picture = (get-item ("URL TO IMAGE FILE"))
$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($Picture)
$pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBox.Width =  $img.Size.Width
$pictureBox.Height =  $img.Size.Height
$pictureBox.Image = $img
$pictureBox.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom
$form.controls.add($pictureBox)
```

The issue is that the logo is displayed, floating on the top of the page.
I use this code to display the form.

```
$form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate() } )
$form.ShowDialog()
```

I don't know if the issue is that I need to "update" the form after showing it the first time or if there's something wrong with the anchor. I tried docking it too, but then it shows on the bottom of the page but behind the other pictureboxes.

Comment: You didn't set a location for the `PictureBox` so it will show at `(0,0)`. Then you set `Anchor` to `Bottom`, so the bottom of your `PictureBox` will keep its distance from the bottom of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$pictureBox.Location = New-object System.Drawing.Size(x,y)`

Play around with the X and Y coordinates in order to get the picturebox in the right place on your form.

EDIT/ADD:

I should add that you can set those coordinates according to the sides (left, right, top, bottom) of other objects you have on your form, something like this:

```
$pictureBox.Location = New-object System.Drawing.Size($formobj.bottom+10,$formobj.right+10)
```